# How to turn off highlight wrapping behavior in RStudio?

Tags: rstudio

I've searched for this, and it is entirely likely that I just couldn't think of the right search terms, so I apologize if this is asked and answered already. I've also checked the RStudio options.

In RStudio, if you highlight a word, and then type a single quote, double quote, or parenthesis, it wraps that word in that character, instead of overwriting the word with the character.

I understand that they're trying to help, but no other editor I work with does that, and I can't get used to it. Is there a way to turn off that behavior?

As an example, if the line of code is: "The quick brown fox", and I highlight the word brown and then type a single quote ('), I get: "The quick 'brown' fox", when what I expected is "The quick ' fox".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Naviagate to the Code preferences pane:

```
Tools -> Global Options... -> Code -> Editing
```

Within, you should see a a select box with the label 'Surround selection on text insertion:' -- try setting that to "Never".